# How to dynamically create ticks (month) in google chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Given an aggregated data table that is defined as:

> aggData: [Date: date][Team: string][Score: number]

I want to plot the aggregated data with the ability to filter by year. I am using dynamic ticks on the hAxis to avoid the repeating labels problem. However, the label for the custom ticks does not appear. 
I want the hAxis to display the months. My hunch is I'm not creating the ticks properly

See images below

```
var hAxisTicks = [];
var dateRange = aggData.getColumnRange(0);

for (var y = dateRange.min.getFullYear(); y <= dateRange.max.getFullYear(); y = y + 1) {
    for(var m = dateRange.min.getMonth(); m <= dateRange.max.getMonth(); m = m + 1){
        hAxisTicks.push(new Date(y,m));
    }
}

var yearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'categoryFilter_div',
    options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: false,
            label: 'Year:',
            labelStacking: 'vertical'
        },
        useFormattedValue: true
    }
});

var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        hAxis: {
                format: 'MMM',
                ticks: hAxisTicks
        }
    }
});

aggData.sort([{ column: 0 }]);

// draw chart
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
dashboard.bind(yearPicker, lineChart);
dashboard.draw(aggData);
```

---

```
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="categoryFilter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

When specifying the hAxisTicks value, the chart comes out without labels on the hAxis
[image]

Without specifying hAxisTicks the chart looks like:
[image]

i've logged the data to console using

```
google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(aggData)
```

the output is:

```
"Oct 1, 2019",128,0,0,0 
"Nov 1, 2019",152,75,0,0 
"Dec 1, 2019",0,0,23,0
"Jan 1, 2020",225,0,0,84
```

Comment: could you possibly share a sample of the data? are you certain the first column in the data table used to draw the chart is a date?

Comment: i've logged the data to console using

google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(aggData)

the output is:
"Oct 1, 2019",128,0,0,0
"Nov 1, 2019",152,75,0,0
"Dec 1, 2019",0,0,23,0
"Jan 1, 2020",225,0,0,84

Comment: not sure, what is the result of --> `console.log(aggData.getColumnType(0));` -- also, please check `hAxisTicks.length`

Comment: Hmm,
console.log(aggData.getColumnType(0)) -->  'date'
console.log(hAxisTicks.length); --> 0 (surprising)
console.log(dateRange.min.getFullYear()); --> 2019
console.log(dateRange.min.getMonth()); --> 9
console.log(dateRange.max.getFullYear()); --> 2020
console.log(dateRange.max.getMonth()); --> 0


i think I need to range the month from dateRange.min.getMonth() to some max for the any given year y which I can't figure out. I know those two for loops are wrong

Comment: so the inner for loop doesn't execute (duh) because the max month in the range is Jan 2020 (so largest month value is 0) and min month in the range is Oct 2019 (so the min  value is 9). And since the min value is greater than the max value it doesn't even run

for(var m = dateRange.min.getMonth(); m <= dateRange.max.getMonth(); m = m + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue with the `for` loop is in the month portion.

given the data you provided, the month for the min date = 9 (Oct)
however, the month for the max date = 0 (Jan)

so the month `for` loop does not run, because 9 > 0

instead, let's use a `while` loop.

```
var dateTick = dateRange.min;
while (dateTick.getTime() <= dateRange.max.getTime()) {
    hAxisTicks.push(dateTick);
    dateTick = new Date(dateTick.getFullYear(), dateTick.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Comment: yes right that does solve this problem, so I will mark this as solved and post another question, which is how to re-calculate the hAxisTicks when you filter on year